# Spring Security Access Denied logging with missing role

Tags: spring, logging, spring-security

Is there an out of the box solution for a access denied logging in spring security.
What I want is basically show which role the user is missing when he gets the access denied exception.

If not, and I have to go down the path of having my own accesssDeniedHandler, how can I access the role configured on that controller which throwed access denied exception.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no concept of "missing roles" out of the box.

Access denied events are published through Spring's standard event mechanism and you can use an `ApplicationListener` to subscribe to these, but there is no assumption that an access decision is purely based on roles in Spring Security. To achieve that, you would need to customize the `AccessDecisionManager` implementation to log information on how it arrived at a particular decision.

The `AccessDeniedHandler` isn't really relevant in this case.